Visual Studio Code very slow and crashing on Parallels Ubuntu VM
Today I created an Ubuntu virtual machine under Parallels on my Macintosh. I installed Visual Studio Code into it. It appeared to run normally, although I had no content to try it on yet.
I installed git, and checked out a repository I'm working on. I rebooted Linux, accepted an update to Parallels. I accepted the accompanying update to Parallels Tools. I installed some libraries.
And now, when I run Visual Studio code, it operates at a snail's pace. Literally, everything takes 20 times as long as it should. Clicking on the Extensions button gets another delay of several seconds, then Code crashes. This is quite repeatable. Rebooting Linux does not help at all. Running code from the terminal did not get me any printout of any sort of error messages.
Is this a known issue with the latest version of Parallels? Or with running Code under Ubuntu? Can someone recommend a good way to diagnose this, or clean it up?

How many processor cores have you assigned to the VM?  You have not provided nearly enough information to diagnose your problem.

Was resolved by rebuilding the VM from scratch.  The first time around, I allowed VSCode to update or install or something while Ubuntu itself was updating, and this proved to be a no-no.
